# Creating a geom histogram that counts both positive/negative ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble plotting the positive `log2_ratio` count on the positive y-axis and the count of the negative `log2_ratio` on the negative-y axis.

In essence, I want the positive count to be above the x-axis while the negative count to be below the x-axis.

Here is the data frame and the code:

```
   chrom      chr_start   chr_stop     num_positions normal_depth tumor_depth log2_ratio gc_content sample
   324202     1 156249804 156249858            55         12.3         4.7     -1.399       34.5     10
   324203     1 156250463 156250473            11         10.0         4.6     -1.109       27.3     10
   324204     1 156250664 156250705            42         12.0         7.4     -0.704       19.0     10
   324205     1 156250816 156250847            32         11.7         4.6     -1.343       40.6     10
   324206     1 156251108 156251132            25         10.6         3.6     -1.569       60.0     10
   324207     1 156251411 156251464            54         12.3         6.8     -0.863       46.3     10

newHist = ggplot(resultsPileup1COMBINED[resultsPileup1COMBINED$sample <= 25,],
          aes(x=sample)) +
          geom_histogram(fill="blue" , bindwidth = 1) +
          geom_histogram(data=resultsPileup1COMBINED[resultsPileup1COMBINED$sample > 25,],
            fill="gray50" , binwidth = 1) +
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1, to = 50, by = 3))
```

Here is a current graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for a completely new graph, try:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(data = resultsPileup1COMBINED[resultsPileup1COMBINED$log2_ratio > 0, ], 
                          aes(x = log2_ratio, y = ..count..)) + 
           geom_histogram(data = resultsPileup1COMBINED[resultsPileup1COMBINED$log2_ratio < 0, ], 
                          aes(x = - log2_ratio, y = - ..count..))
```

In this plot we have the < 0 log2_ratios on the bottom, with the x values negative to line up with the above, using the - ..count.. method

Edit: Asking for a slightly different graph, leaving the above in for posterity.

To graph the number of +/- values for each bin, we plot it out, again using the `-..count..` trick:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(data = 
                          resultsPileup1COMBINED[resultsPileup1COMBINED$log2_ratio < 0, ],
                          aes(x = sample, y = -..count..)) +
           geom_histogram(data = 
                          resultsPileup1COMBINED[resultsPileup1COMBINED$log2_ratio > 0, ],
                          aes(x = sample, y = ..count..))
```

Again, breaks and colours are up to you.

To make it similar to the original plot, make sure you include:

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(from = 1, to = 50, by = 3))
```

Comment: geom_histogram(data = resultsPileup1COMBINED, aes(x = log2_ratio, y = - ..count..)) doesn't necessarily create a count of the negative and positive log2_ratios. It looks like it is creating a sum of the negative log2_ratio values and graphing that for some reason, for x=-1,-2, and -3.

Comment: yup exactly. The positive count would be above the x-axis while the negative would be below.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't look it counted it properly. For example, for patient 2, the graph I posted in the question has a count of about 210. The new graph has a count less than that.

Comment: I deleted all the NAs or 0s before graphing

Comment: it doesn't. the sum of the positive and negative log2_ratio count is 3332 while the nrows is 3344. Also, there are 12 log2_ratios equal to 0. Sorry about that mistake, I must have left out some 0s. The graphs should match but, unfortunately don't.

Comment: I think I found the solution. I'll get back to you as soon as I try out this new code

Comment: Got it!! The reason is because the graph was plotted continuously rather than discrete. Once scale_x_continuous was changed to scale_x_discrete, the graphs matched.

Comment: nice one, I'll just clean up some of my comments and edit the answer